# Limitation on group size with non-parametric permutation tests

Tags: statistical-significance, experiment-design, permutation-test

I would like to know if there is any limitation in the size of the groups when you are implementing non-parametric permutation tests. My case belongs to the realm of medical imaging. I am comparing one patient image versus a group of control images.

For each image (including the patient's), I calculate a maximum T-statistic. This is my 'first level' metric.

In my second level design I use my first level metric to compare the patient against the distribution of the first level metric in the group of controls. I obtain a T-score. Then I permute the labels (patient, control) of my images and obtain again a T-score for that permutation.

I run all permutations where I have one image in the patient group and the rest of the images (30) in the control group.

If I have 1 patient and 30 controls, this will yield 31 permutations with a configuration of 1 patient and 30 controls . After building the permutation distribution with this procedure, I notice that the score for my initial configuration (the one I am testing) does not surpass the 0.05 threshold obtained from the permutation distribution. This is kind of expected, since I don't have enough permutations to have a low enough p-value.

However, (and this is a big however), when I ran ALL possible permutations ($2^{31}$) assigning the label patient or control to each subject, I notice that my initial configuration statistic surpasses the 0.05 threshold. Can I do this, though? Can I run all of the possible permutations when my original design is 1 versus many?

Is there something that I am missing? Or does my procedure seem reasonable?

Comment: It's unclear what you are doing. How do you obtain $2^{31}$ permutations of $31$ things (when there should be $31!\gg 2^{31}$)? What precisely do you mean by a "permutation," then? And of what use is permuting the $30$ control images if they simply remain control images?  And how is it possible that a *single* permutation may have a "low enough p-value" when in fact the p-value needs to be computed *after* the entire permutation test is conducted?

Comment: 0k let me address your questions one by one:

1. I only have two labels. Each subject can be labeled as a control C or as a patient P. 

As I explained I have two cases, one where I just run 31 permutations and other where I run 2^{31} permutations. I obtained 31 permutations by all possible configurations of 1 P and 30 C. Now, in the second case, I have ALL possible permutations, given that each individual can have only two possible labels then I have 2^{31}

Comment: You need to run all permutations to obtain the T-threshold but not to obtain the p-value. The p-value is always given by you. You define the statistical significance by setting the p-value

Under the null hypothesis all permutations have the same probability, hence the probability of a single permutation is 1/N where N is the number of permutations.

If you want a p-value of 0.05, then you just count the permutations required to obtain this value starting from right to left in the permutation distribution histogram (remember each permutation has a probability of 1/N)

Comment: Thank you for your explanations, Diego. You use "p-value" in an unconventional manner to mean what is usually termed the "size" of the test. You use "permutation" in the sense usually meant by "combination": a subset of $\{1,2,\ldots,31\}$. You need to think about how meaningful a combination of more than one patient would be for your study design: was it conducted in such a way that you selected patients randomly from $31$ people and designated the rest as controls? Or perhaps did you select *exactly* one patient randomly from a group of $31$? Or was it something else?

Comment: I think it is rather the second option where I am selecting _exactly_ one out of 31 and calling it the patient.

Comment: Then your "all possible permutations" approach is irrelevant. You're stuck comparing one patient to $30$ others. Using *any* statistic, there is a $2/31\approx 6$% chance your patient will be at one of the two extremes, so for a two-sided test you have no power to detect anything at a $5$% level.